# Step in through referenced assemblies code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-assembly

I've several Visual Studio solutions.

Each solution has several projects generating an assembly.

All of these assemblies are generated by these projects.

So, these assemblies are loaded dinamically using two ways:

- Referenced browsing the assembly location (for example Debug folder of each project).
- NInject (loading classes of whichever assembly containing a classes implements an interface).

Currently, when I need to debug some code of these referenced or loaded assemblies, I need to generate an exception of whichever assembly I'd like to step in, and then Visual Studio, automatically shows me the code.

I figure out there is another way to be able to navigate through my code assemblies, however I've absolutly no idea how to do that.

Comment: You can't just set a breakpoint?

Comment: Remember I'm not able to navigate to source code, or I don't know how to  do that.

Comment: In general you have accessible source files to any code you would like to debug? You are not able to open "all sources at once" - OR - you don't have some at all?

Answer (score 0):

You may open all your solutions at once in several Visual Studio instances.

Then you may start your main process.
In all other VS instances select "Attach to Process ... Ctrl+Alt+P"

[image]

[image]

Find your process and attach to it

[image]

Then you may set breakpoint in any instance of your VS.